# DNS not resolving host names, cannot disable DNS cache

Tags: windows-7, dns

I have an HP laptop with an intel i3 and windows 7 premium home.

Suddenly my DNS is not resolving host names and I cannot disable my DNS cache.  I have tried the ipconconfig/flushdns and it didn't work. I reinstalled my browser. I have checked my network, and router and also tried to disable Dns caching but access was denied.

I don't know what else to check or try at this point.

Any assistance would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Which DNS are you using?

It is possible that the DNS server is having issues. This is particularly common when using the DNS provided via your ISP. But even the big boys have problems. Google DNS died for us a few days ago for a few minutes.

Try switching to either Google DNS or OpenDNS. The best way to do this is by changing the settings on your router. But you can also do it on your PC by going into the settings for your network card (or Wi-Fi connection) and manually setting the DNS entries. Best to do it on the router though if you can and leave the PC to get the setting automatically from the router. You may well need to disconnect and reconnect from the router to pick up the new settings.

Comment: Did this resolve you issue? If So, please accept the solution. Otherwise, would you share what you learned as an answer below. Thanks!